# ggplotly won't work or re-install - is there a way to deinstall it?

Tags: r

I am having a problem I think I may be able to solve my if I could deinstall 'ggplotly' before attempting to reinstall it.

Here's what happened:

Code that worked fine when an instructor demoed it, failed when I tried it at home.  It was R Markdown.  Investigating the problem code cell line by line, the problem was centered around `ggplot2` (which uses `ggplotly`).  Code and error messages are provided below.  In the code "graph" was a `ggplot2 facet_wrap()` that was supposed to pass into `ggplotly`.

Here is the excerpt from my console of the problem and a failed attempt to fix it by re-installing:

```
> ggplotly(graph)
Error in dev_fun(tmpPlotFile, width = deviceWidth, height = deviceHeight) : 
  unable to start png() device
> ggplotly(graph)
Error in RStudioGD() : 
  Shadow graphics device error: r error 4 (R code execution error)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0ar20f/3b613ba7d0ce4228bc937aee7cfcb112.png",  :
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0ar20f/3b613ba7d0ce4228bc937aee7cfcb112.png' for writing
2: In grDevices:::png("C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0ar20f/3b613ba7d0ce4228bc937aee7cfcb112.png",  :
  opening device failed
> install.packages("plotly")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0ar20f/libloc_190_4464fd2b.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can remove an installed package with the function `remove.packages`

Comment: Thanks!  that worked.  Going to post it in the full answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments on this thread, a package can be de-installed with `remove.packages`.  As per the original problem on this post, de-installing and re-installing cleared it, but for completeness, here are all the precautions I took to improve the chances of this working:

1. removed the package as indicated
2. re-initialized RStudio (exited without saving the workspace and re-entered it)
3. By default, it remembered some of my environment so I clicked the broom icon to clear out all variables and data from memory
4. re-installed the package
5. re-loaded the original R file and tested to make sure all worked as expected.

This is what I saw in the console with de-installing and re-installing in contrast to the messages shown on the original post:

During de-installation:

```
> remove.packages("plotly")
Removing package from ‘C:/ProgramFilesCoders/R/R-3.3.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0ar20f/libloc_190_4464fd2b.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

During re-installation:

```
> install.packages("plotly")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/plotly_4.5.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 817502 bytes (798 KB)
downloaded 798 KB

package ‘plotly’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGco6OK\downloaded_packages
```